# What does the "normal" socket of displacement node do?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, node-editor, displacement

I tried searching and there is no information about it.
Blender manual says "to do" 
I did some experiment but still nothing is clear.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

My best guess is that it doesn't do anything now but later you'll be able to displace geometry with a Normal Maps rather than a Bump Map. Which means it will at least save us the hassle of converting a normal map to a bump map, but hopefully this means that we'll get better looking displacement since normal map carries shading information as well as height.